# Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall: print late-commands output

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, curtin, subiquity

I have an autoinstall config:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  late-commands:
    - curtin in-target --interactive --target=/target -- echo "Hello! This is output from late-commands"
```

While executing late commands, it will print:

```
finish:   subiquity/Late/run/command_0: curtin in-target --interactive --target=/target -- echo "Hello! This is output from late-commands"
```

Is there a way to make it print the output of a late-command, too? I want to debug `late-commands`.

Answer (score 3):

#### My solution

I print `/var/log/syslog` on installation error in the `error-commands` autoinstall config section:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - echo "This is the error to debug" && exit 125
  error-commands:
    - tail -200 /var/log/syslog
```

#### How it works

This `subiquity` code handles `early-commands`, `late-commands` and `error-commands`:
https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity/blob/a76581cd2b973b55e55c6ac05b5bf47168493140/subiquity/server/controllers/cmdlist.py#L77-L120

How these autoinstall   keys handle output:

- `early-commands` – echo+syslog
- `late-commands` – syslog
- `error-commands` – echo+syslog if autoinstall else syslog

So in `late-commands` I cannot echo to console. But I can echo from `error-commands`, provided that I am running a non-interactive autoinstall. I use it to print the last lines of syslog, which contain full error message: `This is the error to debug`.